# AS3 - Using an Object to lookup values in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, comparison

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare two arrays for differences and be able to find which elements do not exist in each other. Most examples talk about object lookup for use with a "for each in" loop. That much makes sense, but I have no idea what is going on here:

```
var item:Sprite;    
object_lookup[item] = true;
```

I'm quite confused because I've never seen anything other than an integer inside of [] such as with arrays.

Comment: You should read manuals on `Dictionary` to understand more. Also, `Object`s accept strings as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` is a dynamic, that means you can assign properties to it at runtime:

```
var o:Object = {};

o.sayHi = "Hi, it's me";
trace(o.sayHi); //traces: Hi, it's me

o.sayHiWithFunction = function () { return "Hi with function" };
trace(o.sayHiWithFunction()); //traces: Hi with function
```

If the property you want to assign is not a valid identifier, you have to use the [] and put it as a string, example:

```
var o:Object = {};
o.this = "Yes, it is this!"; // Error, this is a keyword! Won't compile
o["this"] = "And the correct this!"; //And this one works!
o["more words"] = "More words"; //Works too
```

Your code is confusing. If `object_lookup` is an `Object` instance, you created a property on it called `null` but you set this property to true. That means that it will have absolutely nothing to do with the `Sprite` *item* you declared above it. Which is null, of course, as you didn't assign a sprite object to it and that's why the property name gets evaluated to null. Do not confuse here: the property name "null" is just a string, it has nothing to do with the type `null`.
Now, the `for in` loop loops thru all the property names of an Object, and if you know the property names, you can actually look up the values, too. Looks something like this:

```
var o:Object = {a:"A", b:"B", c:"C"}; // This is equivalent to o.a = "A", o.b = "B", o.c = "C"... which is aquivalent to o["a"] = "A" ;)
for(var i in o) {
    trace(i, o[i]) //traces: c C, a A, b B
}
```

The `for each in` is a bit different, if you trace `i`, you will see the values, not the property names as with `for in` loop.
Otherwise do what Vesper suggested you in the comment, read about `Dictionary`.

Comment: Wow. This opens up a lot of new possibilities for me. Thank you for this explanation.